# What settings does Visual Studio 2010 use when calling MiniDumpWriteDump()?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, winapi, visual-c++, visual-studio-debugging, crash-dumps

I've been trying to optimize the size of the dumps generated when our (C++) program crashes.  I was wondering in anyone knew what it was passing to MiniDumpWriteDump() when you tell it to make dump from the debug menu?

It would be a good starting point for pairing down the size of the dumps.

Thanks.

Comment: Only Microsoft knows.  Give them a call.

Comment: That is an odd question... Is it to send dumps over the internet (from a customer) ? Have you tried the different [MiniDump flags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680519(v=vs.85).aspx) ? Are you able to debug with a crash dump to begin with (managing symbols from more than one versions) ?

Comment: Yes, we have a number of scenarios in which we want to write dumps with different acceptable sizes.  One of them is to send them over the internet.  If I include as much info as possible the dump size is over 2 GB right now.